# Rootless Docker: Need to provide write access to a non-root user in docker container for a volume mounted on the host

Tags: docker, docker-volume, rootless

I want to provide write access to a non-root user in a docker container for a volume mounted on the host. I have the same non-root user and group inside container and host as well.

While running the container, I mount a host volume to it `-v /some/folder:/some/folder`. I am doing this because my application running inside the docker container needs to write files to the mounted host folder. But since I am running my application as a non-root user, it doesn’t have permission to write to that folder.

Also, I this mounted folder permission is got changed inside the container automatically.
I have given assigned below user and group as an owner to this folder on the host:
“nonrootuser1:nonrootgroup1”

For 'rootful' docker it works fine, but if it's rootless inside the container it is showing below user and group as an owner to this folder:
“root:nobody”

**Steps to reproduce this**:

1. Add user and group on the host

```
groupadd -g 1015 nonrootgroup1
useradd -u 1099 nonrootuser1
```

2. Create dir which will be assigned to osquery groupadd on the host:

```
sudo su

mkdir -p /var/osquery/sock
echo "hello world" > /var/osquery/sock/file.txt

chown root:nonrootgroup1 /var/osquery/sock
chmod g+s /var/osquery/sock/
```

3. Create Dockerfile in the home directory :

```
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN addgroup -g 1015 -S nonrootgroup1
RUN adduser -D nonrootuser1 -u 1099

USER nonrootuser1:nonrootgroup1

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

4. Run docker container :

```
docker run --rm -d --name sample-app -v /var/osquery/sock:/var/osquery/sock $(docker build . -q)
```

5. Check the user id of the container :

```
dmytro@dmytro:~/dev/sample-image$ docker exec sample-app id

uid=1099(nonrootuser1) gid=1015(nonrootgroup1) groups=1015(nonrootgroup1)
```

6. check the permissions to the /var/osquery/sock dir inside the container :

**Directory /var/osquery/sock is assigned to group 'nobody' instead of 'nonrootgroup1' group**

```
dmytro@dmytro:~/dev/sample-image$ docker exec sample-app ls -lah /var/osquery
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Dec 28 10:47 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Dec 28 10:47 ..
drwxr-s---    2 nobody   nobody      4.0K Dec 28 09:34 sock
```

Host details are mentioned below:

```
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-135-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Storage Driver: overlay2
```

Please suggest.

Thanks!

I tried to setup in the `daemon.json` "userns-remap" config, but docker daemon doesn't start with it, because it lacks permission to create `dockremap` user and group.

Comment: I am confused. Are you running your docker daemon as non-root? Or is it only the container running as non-root? Also can you show your Dockerfile?

Comment: I'm running docker daemon as non-root.

Comment: @Garuno added steps to reproduce this issue.